# Sidekiq memory leak issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq gem to move my heavy reporting jobs to background. The problem is that sidekiq does not release memory even after a job is completed and it is causing an ever increasing memory bloat, resulting in sidekiq restart after every 4-5 jobs. I have tried ActiveRecord::Base.uncached and even tried this in my application.rb - config.middleware.delete "ActiveRecord::QueryCache" but still no use. Even GC.start is not working. How do I clear memory after every job?

Comment: Are you using an old version of sidekiq? The fact that you've tagged this as `ruby-on-rails-3` makes me think, assuming you did tag this correctly, you might be on a very old version. I ask because there have been lots of [performance improvements](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq#performance) to sidekiq over the years, especially in `v4.0`, and your problem might be best solved by upgrading libraries.

Comment: Also, restarting every **4-5 jobs** sounds extreme. What are these jobs doing that's so massively memory-intensive? Is this something you could share?